# Extract private function from javascript using parser

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

I am trying to use a parser (via uglify-js, but any other is fine too) in order to extract private function from input string.

contents of `a.js`

```
var UglifyJS = require('uglify-js');
var ast = UglifyJS.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('b.js').toString());

var stream = UglifyJS.OutputStream({});

// need to manipulate ast here to extract the `sum` function
ast.print(stream)
console.log(stream+'')
```

contents of `b.js`

```
var addRandom = (function() {
    function sum(x, y) {
        return x + y
    };

    return function (input) {
        return sum(input, Math.random());
    };
})();
```

running `node a.js` yields...

```
var fn=function(){function sum(x,y){return x+y}function addRandom(input){return sum(input,Math.random())}return{addRandom:addRandom}}();
```

... but I need to manipulate the ast before being output, to extract the `sum` function. What I want to print out is...

```
function sum(x,y){return x+y}
```

How can I extract the part of the AST tree I want before output?

Comment: You want to extract sum to use it on your script?

Comment: I want to extract private functions from source code as a string value to do with as I please. It is not important to me to retain original formatting. I am hoping to be able to extract private utility functions, and test them by writing them out to an intermediate file, and testing that. In this question, I am interested specifically to know how to extract an arbitrary private function from an ast tree based on the private function's name.

Comment: @haters please don't stop at a down-vote, feel free to unleash your contempt in a comment so we can learn the err of our ways

Comment: You would need to traverse the AST, however I can't find any useful documentation for the node objects other than this: http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/ast

Comment: @MinusFour that is the page I was looking at already :) Perhaps I need to use a different parser/formatter which is designed (and documented) for customising the output.

Comment: Anyway, I would be hesitant about customising the output for runtime use as you would need to compile it during runtime through eval or function (which you should avoid like a plague) and if you are looking to further reduce/optimize the code then I believe you have a better chance exploring and modifying UglifyJS parser/mangler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var UglifyJS = require('uglify-js');
var code = require('fs').readFileSync('b.js').toString();
var stream = UglifyJS.OutputStream({});
var toplevel = UglifyJS.parse(code);
var walker = new UglifyJS.TreeWalker(function(node){
    if (node instanceof UglifyJS.AST_Defun) {
        node.print(stream);
    }
});

toplevel.walk(walker);
console.log(stream + '');
```

Comment: I was coming to the same conclusion myself. This is a nice concise version of pretty much what I have put in my own answer.

Comment: the `console.log` should go after the `toplevel.walk` call, otherwise when there are more than one private function, it will keep outputting the old ones along with the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be manageable with the TreeWalker...

contents of `a.js`

```
var UglifyJS = require('uglify-js'),
    fs = require('fs');

function showPrivates(file) {

    var privates = {};

    UglifyJS.parse(fs.readFileSync(file).toString('UTF-8')).walk(new UglifyJS.TreeWalker(function(node) {
        if (node instanceof UglifyJS.AST_Defun) {
            var stream = UglifyJS.OutputStream({});
            node.print(stream);
            privates[node.name.name] = stream.toString('UTF-8');
        }
    }));

    return privates;

}

console.log(showPrivates('b.js').sum);
```

contents of `b.js`

```
var addRandom = (function() {

    function sum(x, y) {
        return x + y;
    };

    function random(x) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*x);
    };

    return function (input) {
        return sum(input, random(10));
    };
})();
```

... check it out ...

```
console.log(showPrivates('b.js').sum);
// function sum(x,y){return x+y}
```